# Entangled permutations of a multiset

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $M=\{1^{a_1},\dots,m^{a_m}\}$ be a multiset of numbers of cardinality $n$.
Call a permutation of $M$ an $M$-word. We say that an $M$-word $w$ is
*entangled* it cannot be written as a concatenation of two nonempty words $u,v$ such
that $w=u.v$ and the sets of numbers/characters used in $u$ and $v$ are disjoint.

Examples: let $M=\{1^2,2^3,3^4\}$.

The words 122123333, 112323332 are not entagled:

- 122123333 = 12212.3333
- 112323332 = 11.2323332

The words 123213332, 311322233 are entangled.

Question: given a multiset $M$, how many entangled $M$-words are there?

Of course, it is possible to find a horrible-looking formula. But I feel that
this problem should have a nice answer, maybe in a form of a
generating function of some sort.

EDIT:

Another way how one can view entangled $M$-words: as lattice paths from
$s=(0,\dots,0)$ to $e=(a_1,\dots,a_m)$ that avoid all extremal points of
the box except for $s$ and $e$.

Comment: For the record: the horrible-looking formula I found is based on the Moebius inversion of polynomial coefficients with respect to the poset of set partition of $\{1,\dots,m\}$ .

Comment: Does anything nice happen to the horrible-looking formula if $a_1 = a_2 = \ldots = a_m$?

Comment: @mhum: First impression is that nothing really nice happens, but I have to think about it more.

Comment: Why do you "feel that this problem should have a nice answer" in the sense of a nice formula? -- I would probably rather be looking for an efficient algorithm. Note also that a "nice" formula, even if it exists, might not be quite efficient to evaluate.

Comment: @StefanKohl I am hoping for a nice formula, because the number arises in a natural context. My colleague and I have managed to prove that the number of linear extensions $E(P)$ of a *connected* finite poset $P$ is equal to the Euler characteristic of some space $X(P)$. If $P$ is not connected, the Euler characteristic of $X(P)$ is strictly smaller than $E(P)$, but we can show that the connection between $E(P)$ and $\chi(X(P))$ can be expressed in terms of the number of entangled permutations of a multiset $M$ as in my question, $a_i$ are the sizes of connected blocks of $P$.

Comment: @StefanKohl ...and we did *not* not invent/designed the space $X(P)$ to behave like this, it was (basically) defined >40 years ago. So that's why I am hoping: we need the formula, so there should be one. I am an extremely optimistic Platonist, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit.** The answer below is incorrect, but I'll leave it here for others to avoid the same pitfall.

Here is a formula that I would rate $\epsilon$ less than horrible.  Let $M=\{1^{a_1},\dots,m^{a_m}\}$ be a multiset of numbers of cardinality $n$.  The total number of permutations of $M$ is the multinomial coefficient

\[
\binom{n}{a_1, \dots, a_m}:=\frac{n!}{a_1!\cdots a_m!}:=t(M)
\]

It is also easy to count the unentangled permutations in this way.  For a non-empty subset $X:=\{x_1, \dots, x_k\}$ of $[m]$, define

\[
f_M(X):=\binom{a_{x_1}+ \dots + a_{x_k}}{a_{x_1}, \dots, a_{x_k}}.
\]

Note that $f_M(X)$ is the total number of permutations of the numbers in $M$ corresponding to $X$.  So, the total number of entangled permutations is

\[
g(M):= t(M) - \sum_{\emptyset \neq X \subset [m]} f_M(X) f_M ( X^C), 
\]
where $X^C$ is the complement of $X$.

For your example with $M=\{1^2,2^3,3^4\}$, we have $g(M)=1234$.  That looks like a weird number, but if my math is correct, only 26 of the 1260 permutations are untangled.

Comment: In your sum, you count the untangled permutation 112223333 twice,
once for $X=\{1\}$ and second time for $X=\{1,2\}$.


Comment: Yes, you are right.
 I am another victim of overcounting.  I'll leave the answer up for a little while if others find it useful, but will delete it if I can't repair it.  

Comment: @Tony Hyunh: Please, do not delete the answer. The mistake is typical -- everyone I asked (3 people) made exactly this mistake
at first before realizing that the problem is a bit more complicated.
So I think it is better to keep the answer here, but to mark it as wrong.

Comment: @Gejza Jenča: OK, I left the answer as is, but with a warning at the top.  I think one can repair the formula using inclusion/exclusion, but this is probably equivalent to the ugly formula you derived via Moebius inversion.   